# Subversion Switching

Tags: svn, switch-statement, branch

I am seeing behavior out of Subversion I do not quite follow.  (I believe version is 1.6.x, Windows 7).

Anyhoo, I have a workstation test directory that points back to a branch ("Branch A").  At some point, we modified some files for debugging, but that debugging effort turned out to be a dead end (these are not new files, but modified existing files out of SVN).  We never committed those changes, nor did we revert the files back to the control version.

Next test phase, I "Copy" the contents "Branch A" to a new "Branch B".  No problemo there.  On the workstation, I use the "Switch" feature to point from "Branch A" to "Branch B".  I am expecting the modified files (with the red !) to now be unmodified (as they were in "A" and copied into "B") and, therefore, have the happy green check symbol, i.e., the obliterate feature that so many seem to complain about has destroyed our temporary debug mods and replaced it with what is in "B".  Suffice to say, I am here because I am not getting my desired obliteration.

When I "Show Log" the resulting window appears to be telling me that the modified files are indeed pointing to "Branch B".  If I "Update" or explicitly "Set to revision xxx", they still do not budge.  Again, the debug mods never made it into either "Branch A" or "Branch B".

I could delete the whole test folder and check out a new copy from "B", but I would like to understand why the "Switch" function doesn't appear to be working as one might ASSume.  I am also a bit perplexed why the file could be simultaneously a modified version out of "A", and yet claim to be pointing to "B".

Thank you for any insight provided!

Answer (score 0):

> I believe version is 1.6.x, Windows 7.

Do not use Subversion 1.6.x, it is very outdated and does not receive support and security or bug fixes for more than 5 years. The current version is 1.9.x.